# Python Proportion test similar to prop.test in R

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am looking for a test in Python that does this:

```
> survivors <- matrix(c(1781,1443,135,47), ncol=2)
> colnames(survivors) <- c('survived','died')
> rownames(survivors) <- c('no seat belt','seat belt')
> survivors
             survived died
no seat belt     1781  135
seat belt        1443   47
> prop.test(survivors)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  survivors
X-squared = 24.3328, df = 1, p-value = 8.105e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.05400606 -0.02382527
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.9295407 0.9684564
```

I am mostly interested in `p-value` calculation.

The example is taken form [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-test-data-proportions-with-r.html)

Comment: What should I do to improve my question?

Comment: I guess it looks a little like a "please google that for me" question. The statsmodels package + documentation might be an interesting place to look as well: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/stats.html

Comment: @cel, maybe that's way, I did do my own googling though, and I think I eventually got it. If you look the name of the function is pretty different, and I had some problems finding it after googling for "proportion test".

Comment: @cel, and I looked at the link that you provide, but I did not see what I was looking for under "Proportion". But thanks, though.

Comment: Hey, I need something more than p-value. Would you like to help? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333151/python-proportion-test-like-prop-test-in-r

Answer (score 27):

I think I got it:

```
In [11]: from scipy import stats

In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: survivors = np.array([[1781,135], [1443, 47]])

In [14]: stats.chi2_contingency(survivors)
Out[14]: 
(24.332761232771361,       # x-squared
 8.1048817984512269e-07,   # p-value
 1,
 array([[ 1813.61832061,   102.38167939],
       [ 1410.38167939,    79.61832061]]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @Akavall's answer: If you don't explicitly have the "failure" counts (# of deaths in your example), R's `prop.test` lets you specify just the total number of trials e.g. `prop.test(c(1781, 1443), c(1781+135, 1443+47))` would give you the same results as with the contingency table you built.

Scipy's `chi2_contingency` explicitly ask for the failure counts and the complete contingency tables. If you don't explicitly have the failure counts and just want to check whether the proportion of successes out of the total are equal for two samples, you can hack around scipy's function with

```
survivors = np.array([[1781, total1 - 1781], [1443, total2 - 47]])
chi2_contingency(survivors)

# Result:
(24.332761232771361, 8.1048817984512269e-07, 1,
array([[ 1813.61832061,   102.38167939],
           [ 1410.38167939,    79.61832061]]))
```

Took me some time to figure this one out. Hope it helps someone.